# visualize constructions composed of hexahedrons

Tags: python, rotation, vtk, mayavi

I wrote a Python script using matplotlib, to visualize and rotate polycubes  together with planes or axes that reveal symmetry in the polycube. Up to a certain point I succeeded as you can see from the illustrations below. There you see one of seventy-seven possible 3D polycubes of six cubes. My script uses matplotlib and it seems to do a nice job: matplotlib allows me to rotate the polycube and view it at any wanted angle. There is a big problem with most polycubes, which is illustrated in the second image below. A little after I start rotating the polycube, matplotlib shows planes that are partly behind other planes and are therefore partly invisble and not to be drawn or only partly drawn.

I have been searching a lot on forums and with Google, but to no avail. There were hits suggesting that I should use mayavi instead of matplotlib. So I studied extensively on mayavi. I spent literally weeks trying to figure out how to get mayavi going. The hits on docs.enthought seemed promising at first, but although mayavi is clearly suited to the purpose and superb in visualizing objects, I cannot find understandable documentation. I could use a real programmers guide on vtk or tvtk. There is a lot of documentation, but mostly for designers, not programmers. If not available (?) I would also be happy with an example of a script with hexahedrons or irregular grids, that works in canopy's (1.6.2) implementation of python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've modified an example from the vtk documentation (http://www.vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob_plain;f=Examples/DataManipulation/Python/BuildUGrid.py)

This example can be turned into a function which can create the geometry from a point coordinate array and an element array.

I haven't used any guides for vtk, I usually refer to the python examples found here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python

```
import vtk

# Initialize the vtkPoints variable and set the number of points
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
points.SetNumberOfPoints(8)

# Add points to the variable, with the point number first, then the x, y, z coordinates.
# For demonstration purposes, I started numbering the ponts at 10 (normally they would start at 0).
points.InsertPoint(0, 0, 0, 0)
points.InsertPoint(1, 1, 0, 0)
points.InsertPoint(2, 1, 1, 0)
points.InsertPoint(3, 0, 1, 0)
points.InsertPoint(4, 0, 0, 1)
points.InsertPoint(5, 1, 0, 1)
points.InsertPoint(6, 1, 1, 1)
points.InsertPoint(7, 0, 1, 1)

points.InsertPoint(8, 0, 0, 1.1)
points.InsertPoint(9, 1, 0, 1.1)
points.InsertPoint(10, 1, 1, 1.1)
points.InsertPoint(11, 0, 1, 1.1)
points.InsertPoint(12, 0, 0, 2)
points.InsertPoint(13, 1, 0, 2)
points.InsertPoint(14, 1, 1, 2)
points.InsertPoint(15, 0, 1, 2.5)

# Define the hexahedron, then set the point Ids of the hexahedron cell/element.
# From the documentation: points (0,1,2,3) is the base of the hexahedron which, using the right hand rule, forms a
# quadrilaterial whose normal points in the direction of the opposite face (4,5,6,7)
aHexahedron1 = vtk.vtkHexahedron()
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(0, 0) # Cell point 0 corresponds to point 0 which was defined above
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(1, 1)
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(2, 2)
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(3, 3)
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(4, 4)
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(5, 5)
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(6, 6)
aHexahedron1.GetPointIds().SetId(7, 7)

# Define a second hexahedron
aHexahedron2 = vtk.vtkHexahedron()
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(0, 8) # Cell point 0 corresponds to point 8 which was defined above
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(1, 9)
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(2, 10)
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(3, 11)
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(4, 12)
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(5, 13)
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(6, 14)
aHexahedron2.GetPointIds().SetId(7, 15)

# Define an unstructured grid.
aHexahedronGrid = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid()

# Add the hexahedron to the unstructured grid
# Note: this operation defines the point ids, and not the actual point coordinates
aHexahedronGrid.InsertNextCell(aHexahedron1.GetCellType(), aHexahedron1.GetPointIds())
aHexahedronGrid.InsertNextCell(aHexahedron2.GetCellType(), aHexahedron2.GetPointIds())

# Set the points which includes the coordinates. The point ids defined in the line above correspond to the point ids
# that were defined earlier (i.e. points.InsertPoint(10, 0, 0, 0))
aHexahedronGrid.SetPoints(points)

# Now we have defined one hexahedron, and added it an unstructured grid.
# We could create more hexahedrons, and add them to the same unstructured grid.

# To view the unstructured grid, we need to define a mapper and set the unstructured grid as the input
aHexahedronMapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
aHexahedronMapper.SetInputData(aHexahedronGrid)

# Define an actor, and set the mapper as the input
aHexahedronActor = vtk.vtkActor()
aHexahedronActor.SetMapper(aHexahedronMapper)

# Create the usual rendering stuff.
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()) # Change the rotation type from the default to 'trackball'
ren.SetBackground(.1, .2, .4)

# Add the actor to the renderer to actually view the geometry
ren.AddActor(aHexahedronActor)

# Render the scene and start interaction.
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

Comment: I tried the script and it is working exactly as I hoped it would. Of course I will have to find a way to have my particular polycubes in the picture, but that should be no problem at all. The example two-cube is rotating wonderful.

Comment: I'd like to add a thank you to shoe02: thank you shoe02!